# Angular 4 script not working after changing route

Tags: angular

while changing the routes to homepage, javascript and jquery code is not loading in Angular 5

Comment: can you write a alert function in your js code and see if it's getting hit when you change routes?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I create a function and generate a alert, its working. once I click from HOME to ABOUT its working, but Once I coming back from ABOUT to HOME then its only showing page preloader effect, not showing the HOME content, but once I enter on the url, then the HOME page content is showing properly.

Comment: Could you post your js code related to the home content

Answer (score 8):

first, add your script to a .js file and save it under angular.json like below

```
"scripts": ["src/assets/js/modelsupport.js"],
```

add below code in you component.ts that you want it to work

url could start with src/assets or assets according to your angular version

```
url = "assets/js/modelsupport.js";
```

after that include below code in ngOnInit() or where ever you want to call

```
this.loadAPI = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log("resolving promise...");
  this.loadScript();
});
```

after that add loadScript() function in you class

```
public loadScript() {
    console.log("preparing to load...");
    let node = document.createElement("script");
    node.src = this.url;
    node.type = "text/javascript";
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = "utf-8";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(node);
}
```

Hope you could solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

you need to load your script in `ngOnInit()`. This is because when angular changes its route then it does not fire `document.ready`. That's why JS does not called. Adding in `ngOnInit`will solve the problem. It loads JS when ever your `ngOnInit` is being called.

```
ngOnInit(){
    $.getScript('src/assets_v2/js/main.js');
    // do rest of your stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here is an angular way

```
export class PagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  routerSubscription: any;
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recallJsFuntions();
  }

  /**
   * @description when we navigate from one page to another `scope of js funtions`
   * finished so we have to call it again.
   */
  recallJsFuntions() {
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(event => {
        $.getScript('/assets/js/common.js');
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your question I think the problem is with the scripts initialization. Try using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

to initialize scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

Add this code in your `app.component.ts` file

```
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){ 
  
  }

  ngOnInit(){
      $.getScript('/assets/js/custom-script.js'); //Add path to your custom js file
  }

  observer;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      
      console.log('Dom change detected...');
      $.getScript('/assets/js/custom-script.js'); //Add path to your custom js file

    });
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

    this.observer.observe(this.elRef.nativeElement, config);
  }
```

If jQuery code giving error, then

1. Install @types/jquery
2. Add 'jquery' in types:[ ] list of tsconfig file.

In angular page doesn't reload every time, but DOM elements can be loaded or removed. In angular routing; components and DOM elements are dynamically loaded but custom script can only loaded once when page refresh, after loading script, any changes in DOM will not affect script.

For that we have to watch changes in DOM, if there are changes then we load custom script everytime. Mutation Observer detects changes in DOM.

This solution also work with *ngIf problem, where components loaded on condition.

Answer (score 0):

try  after clear browser history or try it with private browsing

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but its not happening with this.

Comment: check the order of route

Comment: if more than one route in route table then first appropriate match will taken. order adding route to table is important . default route will add after adding all the route

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Order is same as in the nav page defined, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` instead of routerLink as a temporary fix.